# Matrix Game SPOJ

Tags: c++, c

I solved [this problem on spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MATGAME/):

> Two players A and B play the following game.
>
> 1. First, a matrix M of size N*M is chosen, and filled with non-zero numbers.
> 2. Player A starts the game and the players play alternately.
> 3. In his turn, a player chooses any row which has atleast one non zero nuumber in it. In this row, the leftmost non zero number is chosen. Let this number be K. The player subtracts any number between 1 and K inclusive from it.
> 4. The game ends when all the numbers in the matrix M are 0.
> 5. The player who plays last wins the game.
>
> Given N,M and the initial matrix, determine who wins the game. Assume that both players play optimally.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases T. 
>     Each test case consists of 2 numbers N and M. There follow N lines each having M integers. The jth number on the ith line is the number M[i][j]. There is a blank line between consecutive test cases.
>
> **Output**
>
> Output T lines, one for each case. Output "FIRST" if player A wins, else output "SECOND".
>
> **Example**
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 3 
> 2 2 
> 1 1 
> 1 1 
>
> 1 3 
> 2 1 1 
>
> 2 2 
> 3 2 
> 3 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> SECOND 
> FIRST 
> SECOND
> ```

It is a grundy numbers problem. I solved it using the traditional grundy approach but another approach I thought of is giving me wrong answer. Here is the second approach:

1. If at a given cell, 1 is present then the player has no choice but to pick it up.
2. Every row is an independent game.(independent of other rows)
3. For a given row, the player who first encouters a number greater than 1 will win that row. Hence to find winner of row, find which player encounters the first number greater than 1 if they play alternatively on that particular row.
4. XOR of winning/losing position of all rows if 0 then first player loses.

What is the fault in this approach?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

//code for fast input of integers
#define gc getchar_unlocked

void scanInt(int &x)
{
    register int c = gc();
    x = 0;
    for(;(c<48 || c>57);c = gc());
    for(;c>47 && c<58;c = gc()) {x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48;}
}
//end of code for fast input

int main(){
    int t,n,m,odds,temp;
    bool wins,flag;
    scanInt(t);
    while(t--){
        wins = false;
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            odds = 0; // stores length of sequence of 1's at the beginning of each row
            flag = true; // set to false on encountering first number not equal to 1 in the ith row
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
                scanInt(temp);
                if(flag == true){
                    if(temp != 1) flag = false;
                    else odds++;
                }
            }
            if((odds % 2) == 1) wins ^= false;
            else wins ^= true; //wins is XOR of result of each row as a separate game
        }
        puts(wins == true ? "FIRST\n" : "SECOND\n"); //if XOR of result of all rows is zero then first player loses
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Giving me wrong answer" is rather vague, you should show what answer it gives you (assuming what you expect is already shown in the question Example section).

Comment: As a side note, optimizations like `x = (x<<1) + (x<<3) + c - 48` are both good at hiding bugs, and likely to produce worse code than modern optimizing compiler would produce, especially on a modern CPU with good multiplication instruction... A good start for debugging would be to write clearer code. There's a famous quote about premature optimization...

Comment: And then, more importantly, always check return value of `scanf` functions. If it's less than expected, do not use the uninitialized out parameters.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to find the winner of each row without considering the others. Since players can switch rows from turn to turn they might take two turns on one row while their opponent focused on a different row.